# Use $or with nested array of objects in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have the following collection

```
[
  {"overlaps": [{"BB1": "itemA", "iou": 0.1,  "BB2": "itemB"},{"BB1": "itemB", "iou": 0.4,  "BB2": "itemC"}], "City": "Paris", "mode": "RGB","path": "photo1.png"},
  {"overlaps": [{"BB1": "itemA", "iou": 0.5,  "BB2": "itemC"}], "City": "London", "mode": "RGB","path": "photo2.png"},
  {"overlaps": [{"BB1": "itemB", "iou": 0.8,  "BB2": "itemB"}], "City": "London", "mode": "greyscale","path": "photo3.png"},
  {"overlaps": [{"BB1": "itemA", "iou": 0.2,  "BB2": "itemC"},{"BB1": "itemA", "iou": 0.8,  "BB2": "itemC"}], "City": "Berlin", "mode": "RGB","path": "photo4.png"},
  {"overlaps": [{"BB1": "itemA", "iou": 0.9,  "BB2": "itemB"}], "City": "NY", "mode": "greyscale","path": "photo5.png"},
  {"overlaps": [{"BB1": "itemA", "iou": 0.8,  "BB2": "itemB"}], "City": "Roma", "mode": "RGB","path": "photo6.png"}
]
```

I would like to retrieve documents that

- have city = berlin
- OR have mode = greyscale
- OR countains at least one overlap between "BB1":"itemA" and "BB2":"itemC"

The first 2 conditions are easy:

```
cursor = record1.find({"$or": [{"City":"Berlin"},{"mode":"greyscale"}]})
```

How can I add the third condition to the query?

Comment: Please don't repost questions. You have not improved anything and you're destroying the thread of conversation

Comment: @NeilLunn I deleted the previous question, I understand it was unclear.  I think this one is very simple. I want to have 3 conditions in my OR. I know how to make 2 of them. I dont know how to make the 3 of them together. If you can help it will be great. Thank you.

Comment: This is actually worse. Instead you should undelete your previous question and make it clearer. At least there's some commentary on guidance there.

Comment: @NeilLunnI deleted the question because deleted his comment and all the thread of our conversation disapeared.

Comment: Just a remark, if you find that you struggle to create the query you need, perhaps it's best to rethink your schema design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should need to apply `$elemMatch` with `$or` condition to obtain the result

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [{ City: "Berlin" }, { mode: "greyscale" },
    {
      overlaps: {
        $elemMatch: {
          $or: [
            {
              BB1: "itemA",
              BB2: "itemC"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```